# How to make sure all of the nodes process one API request behind a load balancer

Tags: design, architecture, scalability

I have an architectural question. I have an application which is subscribed to a log compacted Kafka topic. I have to process each event and store into a persistent datastore. I am planning to run the app in 4 instances with the same group-id so that the partitions are distributed with all the nodes.

During the lifetime of the application, there will be a need for

- Resetting consumer to start from 0th offset
- Pausing the consumer for a while
- Resuming a paused consumer

The best way to achieve this was to implement an API which can be called from a script. The API will have an access to the KafkaConsumer object and will call the `pause` operation.

Now, the issue I see with this approach is there isn't a way I know which can ensure all of the 4 instances. How can I make sure that one API (or N API where N = number of instances) call will do this operation?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is to basically control all of the instances of Kafka processing nodes, well, you already have Kafka. Why not introduce a "command" topic which all nodes subscribe to? You can send one command from your "api" that all the nodes will receive (as long as they have different group ids).

Comment: Thank you Robert for suggesting an approach. Would you be able to point to some reference or example of a command topic?

Comment: I think you were referring to : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#kafka_mq